# Javascript replace string characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I already am doing a replace for the commas in an textbox. How would I replace if there is an "$" and a comma also in the same line?

```
function doValidate()
{
var valid = true;

document.likeItemSearchForm.sup.value = document.likeItemSearchForm.sup.value.replace(/\,/g,''); 

return valid;   
}
```

Comment: Why do you escape the comma? It has no special meaning in a regex.

Comment: FYI, you should tag the answer as accepted if you find it adequate.

Answer (score 10):

Do you want to replace commas and dollar signs? Here's how:

```
"$foo, bar.".replace(/\$|,/g, "")
```

The regexp matches dollar signs or commas. The `g` flag tells it to match the entire string instead of stopping after the first match.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the prompt reply!!

Comment: document.likeItemSearchForm.sup.value = document.likeItemSearchForm.sup.value.replace(/\$|,/g,'');

Comment: Works fine for me, in both Firebug and the Node.JS console.

Comment: I think `/[$,]/g` would be better

Comment: how to replace following character from the string using query string "[","]"